# can i pass more than one parameter within SOUNDEX() function to get multiple value result

Tags: mysql

My student table `stu_table` contains many different student name but most of them sound similar, in the field `stu_name`.

For example:

```
Mrinmoy, Minmay, Mrinmay, Minmoy, 
Tanmoy ,Tanmay, Tonmoy, Tanmy, 
Rajesh, Rajes, 
Anirban, Anirbon.
```

- Here first 5 make a similar sound group of name
- Next 3 make a similar sound  group of name
- and last 2 make another group of similar sound name.

Can i pass more than one parameter (for example Mrinmoy and Tanmoy) within a single `SOUNDEX()` function to fetch both result.

If yes then how to pass it. Please help.

Comment: It seems only a matter of mysql and no PHP (or you are referring to this: [php-soundex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php)?). In mysql, tried use `SOUNDEX(...) OR SOUNDEX(...)`?

Comment: In my experience, SOUNDEX is a clever but ultimately unsatisfactory function. I think you'd do better to find an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

soundex() accept only one parameter.
So you have to use OR in sql.
You can try this sql.

```
SELECT * FROM `stu_table` where soundex(`stu_name`)= soundex('Anirban') OR soundex(`stu_name`)=soundex('Tonmoy')
```